# Workday Integration SOAP API - Launch EIB Request

Tags: soap, integration, launch, workday-api

**Workday Integrations:**
We have an requirement wherein I want to extract data from the workday using 'Launch EIB'.

1. We have created EIB using 'Create EIB'.
2. Also,We have created a Custom Report using the Workday GUI.
3. The custom report takes two input parameter: 1.Company and 2.Fiscal Year
4. The output is stored on sFTP in an xml file.

Using Workday GUI, I am able to get the output file on sFTP.

Now I want to call the 'Launch EIB' API from Workday SOAP API and for that, I am not clear on Request structure.

I tried giving value for input parameters
I am getting the error as below:

"The Override Field "Year", whose return type is "Fiscal Years for RDS", expects the appropriate attribute/instance element to be populated within the Field Override Data subelement."

Can anybody please help me with Launch EIB Request Structure, how to provide value for service component Data in the request,Considering Report name as 'Custom_report_JournalData' and Two Fields 'Company' and  'Fiscal Year'.

Request structure for Launch EIB  is as in the [API Documentation link](https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Integrations/v25.2/Launch_EIB.html):

Any help in this regards, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would generally do this.

1. A Use the web service tester in Workday Studio. Use that and the Xml request template it creates to get the request working. Then build the same request in another tool you can automate 
   Or
2. Use SoapUi to consume the WSDL for this web service . Get the request working in SoapUI first
3. Use wsdl2java to create all the necessary Java classes for calling the Launch EIB service . Then write the call programmatically .

I have code sitting around for launching Studio integrations this way and EIB launch seems to be similar. Let me know if you would like to see the code for studio launching.